# tmux won't unbind Ctrl+b - (Delete the most recent paste buffer)

Tags: tmux

It seems like I can't unbind/rebind keys. In this scenario, I'm trying to change the split-window keys, but tmux doesn't seem to honor my config file.

For example, I'll try to 'split-window -v' via `Ctrl+b -`, but the tmux status bar spits out 'No buffer', meaning that it still has the default action of 'Delete the most recent paste buffer
' for `Ctrl+b -`

Here is my ~/.tmux.conf file contents:

```
unbind - 
unbind '"'
unbind %
bind | split-window -h
bind - split-window -v
```

I've tried calling out my conf file just in case tmux for some reason wasn't loading my conf file, but to no avail:

```
$ tmux -f ~/.tmux.conf
```

`Ctrl+b ?` output shows that none of my rebindings are loaded.

Running tmux 3.2a on Ubuntu 22.04.3.

Comment: `tmux -f ~/.tmux.conf` creates a new tmux session, but the `-f` will work only if the command also starts a new tmux server, which will happen if there is no server already. If there is a tmux server, you can tell it to parse the file again by invoking `tmux source-file ~/.tmux.conf`. Does the problem exist when you handle this right?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski - My hero. `tmux source-file ~/.tmux.conf` did the trick. Embarrassingly I had another session open that I wasn't aware of. I guess because I had an unattached session still open, tmux wouldn't load the changes via `tmux` or `tmux -f ~/.tmux.conf` to the config file since a server was already running?

Comment: Yes. From the manual [where it describes `-f`](http://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-current/man1/tmux.1#f) [emphasis mine]: "tmux loads configuration files **once** when the server process has started. The `source-file` command may be used to load a file later."